# What is === in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Looking into the answer of **Chris Brandsma** in [Advanced JavaScript Interview Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069857/advanced-javascript-interview-questions) what is  `===` in Javascript.

If possible please provide a simple example

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which "equal" operator I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript, it is somehow related to your question...

Comment: You can always check the latest official standard for EcmaScript, [ECMA-262, 5th Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf).

EcmaScript is the basic language of what is commercialized as JavaScript (browsers), ActionScript (Adobe Flash), etc.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

=== is the strict equal operator. It only returns a Boolean True if both the operands are equal and of the same type. If a is 2, and b is 4,

```
a === 2 (True)
b === 4 (True)
a === '2' (False)
```

vs True for all of the following,

```
a == 2 
a == "2"
2 == '2'
```

Answer (score 13):

=== is 'strict equal operator'. It returns true if both the operands **are equal AND are of same type.**

```
a = 2
b = '2'
a == b //returns True
a === b //returns False
```

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/javascript/comparison.html).

Answer (score 0):

please refer [Strict Equality Check](http://www.webreference.com/js/column26/stricteq.html)..